# Slow implementation and runs out of heap space (even when vm args are set to 2g)

Tags: java, optimization, tree, traversal

I'm writing a function which generates all paths in a tree as xpath statements and storing them in a bag below is a naive (sorry this is long) and below that is my attempt to optimize it:

```
/**
 * Create the structural fingerprint of a tree. Defined as the multiset of
 * all paths and their multiplicities
 */
protected Multiset<String> createSF(AbstractTree<String> t,
        List<AbstractTree<String>> allSiblings) {
    /*
     * difference between unordered and ordered trees is that the
     * next-sibling axis must also be used
     * 
     * this means that each node's children are liable to be generated more
     * than once and so are memo-ised and reused
     */

    Multiset<String> res = new Multiset<String>();

     // so, we return a set containing:
     // 1. the node name itself, prepended by root symbol

    res.add("/" + t.getNodeName());
    List<AbstractTree<String>> children = t.getChildren();

    // all of the childrens' sets prepended by this one

    if (children != null) {

        for (AbstractTree<String> child : children) {

            Multiset<String> sub = createSF(child, children);

            for (String nextOne : sub) {
                if (nextOne.indexOf("//") == 0) {
                    res.add(nextOne);
                } else {
                    res.add("/" + nextOne);
                    res.add("/" + t.getNodeName() + nextOne);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // 2. all of the following siblings' sets, prepended by this one

    if (allSiblings != null) {

         // node is neither original root nor leaf 
         // first, find current node

        int currentNodePos = 0;
        int ptrPos = 0;

        for (AbstractTree<String> node : allSiblings) {
            if (node == t) {
                currentNodePos = ptrPos;
            }
            ptrPos++;
        }

         // 3. then add all paths deriving from (all) following siblings 

        for (int i = currentNodePos + 1; i < allSiblings.size(); i++) {
            AbstractTree<String> sibling = allSiblings.get(i);

            Multiset<String> sub = createSF(sibling, allSiblings);

            for (String nextOne : sub) {
                if (nextOne.indexOf("//") == 0) {
                    res.add(nextOne);
                } else {
                    res.add("/" + nextOne);
                    res.add("/" + t.getNodeName() + nextOne);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

And now the optimization which is (currently) in a subclass:

```
private Map<AbstractTree<String>, Multiset<String>> lookupTable = new HashMap<AbstractTree<String>, Multiset<String>>();

public Multiset<String> createSF(AbstractTree<String> t,
        List<AbstractTree<String>> allSiblings) {

    Multiset<String> lookup = lookupTable.get(t);
    if (lookup != null) {
        return lookup;
    } else {

        Multiset<String> res = super.createSF(t, allSiblings);

        lookupTable.put(t, res);
        return res;
    }
}
```

My trouble is that the optimized version runs out of heap space (the vm args are set at -Xms2g -Xmx2g) and is very slow on moderately large input.  Can anyone see a way to improve on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code eats RAM exponentially. So one layer more means `children.size()` times more RAM.

Try to use a generator instead of materializing the results: Implement a Multiset which does not calculate the results beforehand but iterates through the tree structure as you call `next()` on the set's iterator.

Answer (score 1):

Run the code through a profiler. That's the only way to get real facts about the code. Everything else is just guesswork.

Answer (score 1):

"generates all paths in a tree as xpath statements"

How many paths are you creating?  This can be non-trivial.  The number of paths should be **O**( *n* log *n* ), but the algorithm could be much worse depending on what representation they use for children of a parent.

You should profile the simple enumeration of paths without worrying about the bag storage.